# Is there a way to get the line of the currently executing s-expression?

Tags: init-file

Say I have a some code in my init file (line numbers are marked on the left-side margin):

```
 1.
 2.
 3.
 4.
 5. (let ((a 1))
 6.   (message "a%s steak sauce" a))
 7.
 8.
 9.
10.

=> "a1 steak sauce"
```

Is there a function to get the line of the currently executing s-expression (something like the following)?

```
 1.
 2.
 3.
 4.
 5. (let ((a 1))
 6.   (message "a%s steak sauce" a)
 7.   (message "currently executing s-expression on line: %s"
 8.            (get-currently-executing-s-expression-line)))
 9.
10.

=> "currently executing line: 5"
```

Comment: Define "currently executing". Are you asking for a message to be shown periodically, or for each "line" of code? If not, when/how do you want to "get" this line? 
In any case, you probably want to notify based on the current sexp, not a source-code line. Your init file is read and processed a sexp at a time, not a textual line at a time. It's about Lisp sexps, not code lines that you see.

Comment: Knowing the line of the currently executing sexp would work just as well. I'll edit the question

Comment: This smells like it might be an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you are really trying to do? Are you trying to debug your init file?

Comment: I don't believe it's an X-Y question. Knowing the line of the currently executing s-expression in my init file is a crucial piece of data for the extension that I'm writing

Comment: Again, how/when do you expect to "get" the currently executing sexp? It's hard (for me) to guess what you're expecting to do or be done. If you aim to step through your init file, sexp by sexp, then that sounds like using the debugger. If not stepping, then what - how do you expect to invoke the code that gives you the line of the "current sexp"? What defines "current" for you?

Comment: That could be a clue; I'll look into how edebug instruments a piece of code to find the line number.

I expect to get the currently executing sexp when the init file is being loaded.

So after Step 5: "It does some basic parsing of the command-line arguments." and before Step 7: "It calls the function package-activate-all ..." in the sequence of actions at startup (maybe after step 7; haven't thought that far yet)

Comment: You'll probably get more traction (and more help) if you described what your extension is supposed to do (in high level terms). If you cannot describe it in a short paragraph, then that probably indicates a problem.

Comment: Please note that your source code isn't evaluated *at all*. It is just text. The lisp reader reads the text and generates lisp objects from it. Those lisp objects (which do not exist in any file) are what is evaluated.  You can get a printed representation of the objects, but that is more akin to a *reconstruction* of the source code, and it is not guaranteed to be the same code, and nor would it have any direct ties to lines of text in the original file.  The edebug debugger will undoubtedly be going to quite some effort to provide those associations.

Comment: What @NickD said. A clearer question is more likely to get helpful answers. Comments can be deleted at any time. They're not the place to put answers. If some of what you see in the comments helps clarify the question, then please update the question accordingly, as if the comments were gone. That will help others find the Q&A etc.

Comment: @NickD ok, at a high level, my extension (defined at the top of my init file), at load-time (Step #14: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html) should be able to examine the s-expressions of my init file; hence giving me the ability to examine certain pieces of metadata of an s-expression. e.g., line number of s-expression, etc.

Comment: I suppose, at an even higher level, I could describe it as, _an init file that can read itself_

Comment: How would I (a naive user, not a lisp programmer) use it? What can I ask it? *How* can I ask it? What would it tell me?

Comment: Getting line numbers is going yo be tricky, as the others have pointed out. Would simple signposts work instead? For passive monitoring of my init, I use eg. `(message "loaded section 1")`. If I want to actively step through it, debug is the usual approach, or just evaluating each line manually

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is probably an X-Y problem. It is also likely that you have solved problems like this in the past by using the `__LINE__` macro in C, or something analogous, and you’re reaching for the familiar solution. Sometimes the familiar solutions are not the best! However, I will try to answer the question.

The short answer is just “No”. The long answer is much more interesting.

First, your example is somewhat problematic, because it says that “line 5” is being executed while actually the sexps on lines 5, 7, and 8 are all on the stack at that point. You seem to want it to print line 5 because that is the current top–level form. I think it would be more natural to print “line 8”, because that is the current inner–most form that you would care about (assuming you don’t want to see a line number from whatever file contains the definition of `get-currently-executing-s-expression-line`.)

I don’t know very many details about how Emacs keeps track of what code it is currently executing, but I assume that there must be a stack. (Can you name any systems that don’t have a stack?! I think they all went extinct.)

Ok, I kinda lied. I have already used the Emacs debugger once or twice before, and I know that it shows you the stack in a buffer. Therefore there must be some code in Emacs which puts the details about the stack into the buffer. We can read that code, therefore we can easily figure out how it works.

First let’s take a look at that stack, to remind ourselves what it looks like. Try putting this in the `*scratch*` buffer and executing it:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (message "a%s steak sauce" a)
  (message "currently executing s-expression on line: %s"
           (debug)))
```

Calling `debug` just dumps you straight into the debugger; there are other ways to get into the debugger, but this is the most useful for this example. Here’s the stacktrace that I see:

```
Debugger entered: nil
  (message "currently executing s-expression on line: %s" (debug))
  (let ((a 1)) (message "a%s steak sauce" a) (message "currently executing s-expression on line: %s" (debug)))
  eval((let ((a 1)) (message "a%s steak sauce" a) (message "currently executing s-expression on line: %s" (debug))) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> eval-last-sexp (nil nil))
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (eval-last-sexp nil nil))
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

The bottom 9 lines are all about me calling `eval-last-sexp` (bound to `C-x C-e` by default). Then that calls eval on my source code, and the top two lines are the ones we actually care about. If we could get line numbers for those frames, then we could pick among them to answer your question.

Now we can look at the code that generated this buffer. I decided to start with the `debug` function. `C-x h f` asks for a function name, so I typed in `debug` and hit enter. This got me a description of the function, and most importantly, a link to the source code. I clicked that link. I saw that `debug` is a long and complicated function, but right in the middle I saw a call to `debugger-setup-buffer`. That sounded promising, so I put the point on it and hit `M-.` to jump to the definition.

The first thing that `debugger-setup-buffer` does is set the variable `backtrace-frames` to the result of calling `backtrace-get-frames`. This seems very promising indeed!

`backtrace-get-frames` calls `mapbacktrace`, passing in am anonymous function that pushes something into a local variable. Eliding some of the details, this is what I see:

```
(let ((frames nil))
    (mapbacktrace (lambda (…)
                    (push …
                          frames))
                  …)
    …)
```

So this is using `mapbacktrace` to copy the details of each frame into an ordinary Lisp list. Presumably that list is folded, spindled, and mutilated before finally getting printed out.

If we pull that out into the `*scratch*` buffer, edit it slightly, run it with `C-u C-x C-e`, and then edit the result for readability, this is what we get:

```
(#s(backtrace-frame t mapbacktrace ((lambda ... ...)) nil nil nil nil)
 #s(backtrace-frame nil let ((...) (mapbacktrace ...) (setq frames ...) frames) nil nil nil nil)
 #s(backtrace-frame t eval ((let ... ... ... frames) nil) nil nil nil nil)
 #s(backtrace-frame t elisp--eval-last-sexp (nil) nil nil nil nil)
 …)
```

It’s a longish list of `backtrace-frame` objects that hold onto the details about each frame. `mapbacktrace` gives us all the information about the frame, and we could do with that what we want; we don’t have to use `backtrace-frame` objects if we don’t want to.

You have probably noticed that the filename and line number are not shown. `mapbacktrace` gives us the form being called and any arguments to it, but nothing about the file or line number. Emacs just does not keep the file name and line number around like you would expect. It doesn’t need to in most cases; instead it keeps around the result of parsing the file. That “result of parsing” is an ordinary Lisp list that can be printed out or examined at any time; you can see it included in the backtrace objects above. In other languages this would be called an Abstract Syntax Tree. Lisp predates the invention of that name, so we just call it a list.

So whatever it was you were trying to do is going to need an unfamiliar solution, rather than a familiar one. If all you want to do is step through your init file, put a (debug) at the top and then single–step the debugger by pressing `d` repeatedly. (`C-h m` will tell you about other commands available in the debugger). If you want to print out a report about functions that were called, then perhaps tracing is a better choice. You can call `trace` on any function and every call to that function will generate a log message in the `*Trace*` buffer. The log messages will include the argument values and return value, and if a traced function calls other traced functions, the log messages will be nested to make that plain.

I recommend asking one or more high–level questions that are quite explicit about the exact features you want. We may be able to recommend existing features or packages that can do the job, but until you ask those questions we’ll be left guessing.