# How to read an s-expression at load-time

Tags: init-file, load, read

Why does it seem impossible to read an s-expression at load-time?

Given this and only this s-expression in my init file:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (end-of-defun)
  (beginning-of-defun)
  (setq beg (point))
  (setq form (funcall load-read-function (current-buffer)))
  (setq end (point))
  (message "BEG:  %s" beg)
  (message "FORM: %s" form)
  (message "END:  %s" end))
```

On startup, I receive the error:

```
End of file during parsing: /home/user/.emacs.d/init.el
```

---

Now, also curiously, if I comment out the erroneous lines:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (end-of-defun)
  (beginning-of-defun)
  (setq beg (point))
  ;; (setq form (funcall load-read-function (current-buffer)))
  (setq end (point))
  (message "BEG:  %s" beg)
  ;; (message "FORM: %s" form)
  (message "END:  %s" end))
```

On startup, I get this output in the Messages buffer:

```
BEG:  1
END:  1
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
```

No matter where I place that s-expression `(point)` will always be `1`. Why's that?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand how I'm not making this question understandable. The end goal is to get the line information of the currently-being-read/evaluating s-expression at load-time

Comment: It's not that the question is not understandable. It is, and @phils provided an answer. The problem is that you seem to expect something else. What's not clear is what that something else is. My hope was that you could explain *why* you are interested in what that snippet above does: what are you trying to do? If the end goal is what you say it is, then your [other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68275/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-line-of-the-currently-executing-s-expression) seems more to the point and has some comments that indicate a way forward.

Answer (score 1):

> On startup, I get this output in the Messages buffer:
>
> ```
> BEG:  1
> END:  1
> For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
> ```
>
> No matter where I place that s-expression (point) will always be 1. Why's that?

Notwithstanding that you've called `(beginning-of-defun)` and then set both `beg` and `end` to that same value, you're also processing an empty buffer by default, so those values could be expected to be `1`.

Are you expecting that Emacs would visit your init file source code in a buffer, and select that buffer by default, while it evaluates your init code?

```el
(message "%S (%S)" (current-buffer) (buffer-string))
```

gives me: `#<buffer *scratch*> ("")` if I evaluate it on start-up.

If you specify a file argument when you start Emacs, then you would be processing one of those buffers, so maybe this does what you want?

`emacs ~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: My example is this snippet: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/elisp-mode.el#L1361-L1366. `beg` and `end` are not the same value. And it can be proven at runtime. I don't understand where I'm failing to explain what I'm trying to do. I feel like it's a simple and intuitive question

Comment: `(message \"%S (%S)\" (current-buffer) (buffer-string))` doesn't work for me (version "28.0.50"). Where are you placing that form in the init file? I'm getting the error: `Symbol's value as variable is void: "%S`

Comment: _Are you expecting that Emacs would visit your init file source code in a buffer, and select that buffer by default, while it evaluates your init code?_ I'm expecting that Emacs evaluates said form in my init file; not before my init file; not after my init file; but as my init file. I don't understand how I can simplify my question anymore than what I have

Comment: I think the correct expression to use is `(message "%S (%S)" (current-buffer) (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))`. Adding that to your snippet will tell you what buffer emacs is visiting at the time and its contents.

Comment: Emacs *did* evaluate said form: if you examine the messages (including the one that prints out the current buffer and its contents), you will see it was visiting the `*scratch*` buffer and it was empty. So `(point)` returned 1 in both calls and both `BEG` and `END` were set to 1. @phils explained that in the answer, but you seem to expect something else. We are all trying to understand what that something else *is*.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your understanding of my question now. So, when my init file is being evaluated (Step #14: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html), the current buffer is the `*scratch*` buffer? My assumption was (and is (but must be wrong)) that the current buffer would be `#<buffer init.el>`

Comment: Apologies for the syntax error -- I was originally going to propose doing that on the command line with `--eval` and I accidentally kept my shell escaping for the quotes when I amended my answer. Thanks for clarifying that NickD.

Comment: @JohnDeBord: Even if that buffer existed (and it probably doesn't), it would cause utter chaos if the current buffer continually changed to be a buffer of the source code for whatever elisp was currently being evaluated.  Calling one function would switch the current buffer to library A, and calling another function would change it to library B.  The idea makes no sense at all.  The current buffer is whatever it's been set to initially, and it stays that way until it is told to change.

Comment: If I put `(message "%S" (buffer-list))` in an init file, the result is `(#<buffer *scratch*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*> #<buffer *Messages*> #<buffer  *code-conversion-work*> #<buffer  *load*>)` -- these are the only buffers which exist while the init file is being evaluated.